# Using existing table in sqlalchemy

Tags: sql-server, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

Is there a way where I can use an existing table in my sql server with SQLAlchemy? I want to insert data and I want to use an existing table, a table I didn't define using classes.

I am using Python 2.7 and SQLAlchemy 0.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is [possible in 0.8](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/reflection.html#reflecting-database-objects) by defining a `autoload`-ed table:

```
foo = Table('foo', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
```

Table columns can be accessed via `foo.c`:

```
print list(foo.c)
```

Starting from 0.9.1, SQLAlchemy has experimental [extension called `automap`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html).